# OpenLayers 6: blur effect with ImageStatic

Tags: javascript, openlayers, image

I'm using a static image on my map in a project with Django. The code is inspired to the [official example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html):

```
var imageSourceExtent = [
  12.1986543459999996,
  44.9052984770000023,
  12.3448225140000005,
  44.9825835529999978,
]

var imageSourceProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:4326',
  extent: imageSourceExtent,
});

var imageSource = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
  url: '{% static 'gis-data/raster/clip_NDVI_color4326.png' %}',
  projection: imageSourceProjection,
  imageExtent: imageSourceExtent,
});

var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: imageSource,
});

var outDoors = new ol.layer.Tile({
  type: 'base',
  title: 'Topographic',
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      attributions: 'powered with <a href="https://openlayers.org/" target="_blank">OpenLayers</a>',
      url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/maxdragonheart/...'
    }),
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
      outDoors,
      imageLayer,
    ],
  target: 'map',
    render: 'canvas',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(ol.extent.getCenter(imageSourceExtent)),
    zoom: 12,
  })
});
```

I've used QGIS to create the png from a tif and inside QGIS I see the image in this way:

[image]

But when I see the same image on the map it appear in this way with a blur effect:

[image]

Why happen this? How I can solve?

Comment: At which zoom? When zoom resolution will match actual image resolution, there will be no blurr.

Comment: I can see this from zoom 14 @TomazicM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the indication from @TomazicM I've changed the resolution of the image from 10 meter to 0.5 meters and now I can see correctly the image until zoom level 19.

Comment: You can alsp disable image smoothing to get a sharper image when zoomed in.  In the next release there will be an imageSmoothing option https://codesandbox.io/s/static-image-71dc9 or you can set it in the context in the layer's prerender event https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/sea-level.html